# Problem with manifolds and submanifolds

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Let $N$ be a compact submanifold of dimensional k in $\mathbb R^n$. Consider the subset L of $S^{n-1}\times N$ which consist all of the pair (v,x) such v are orthogonal $T_xN$. ( $S^{n-1}$ is sphere)
I need to prove that L is submanifold of $S^{n-1}\times L$ and find dimensional of L. 
So, I need find a map (U,$\phi$) for all points of L such U$\cap$L=$\phi^{-1}(\mathbb R^k\cap \phi(U))$ where k is dimensional of L which I need to find too, and I have no idea have to do it.

Comment: maybe someone has idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of mistakes in the text associated with the letter $L.$ Nevertheless, probably I've realized what you want.
Do you know what it means to be orthogonal in terms of coordinates? You have to take some covering of your compact manifold and write equations for the vectors connected with your condition. It's pretty easily if you know what is the "dot product".

Comment: "Do you know what it means to be orthogonal in terms of coordinates?" It means that dot product equals to 0. But what kind of covering I should take?

Comment: It doesn't matter, that is, you know that it's compact manifold, therefore there exists some covering by definition of smooth manifold (and it'll be finite if you want it...)

Comment: Well, I wrote an expression which follows from the orthogonality: $\sum\limits_iv_ix_i = 0$ and how does it prove that $L$ is submanifold?

Comment: Oh, may be because it is a set of the level of the original manifold?

Comment: Is it right or not?

Comment: I wanted to tell you to pay attention to the normal vector bundle of your compact manifold and your $L$ is a obvious submanifold.
Regarding your function: could you write a little more because I don't understand how you construct a level set.

Comment: So, $L$ is submanifold because it is a vector bundle for $N$?But for vector bundles we need an isomorphism of vector spaces?  ( I corrected the conditions). Then the dimensional of $L$ is $k-1$?